# Android fullscreen fragment does not show elements behind the navigation and status bars

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-fullscreen

I am developing an Android game. It is composed of one main activity and several fragments and the navigation through them is handled via the navigation component. I have a small problem that is driving me crazy. The main activity is correctly set fullscreen, the status and button bars are hidden correctly and the background image that i chose is showed entirely fullscreen.   Speaking of the fragments instead, it seems like their elements are hidden below the status bar or that the size of the layout does not respect the actual size of the screen. If i place a button at the very bottom of the layout as you can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD4B3.png) what actually happens on the screen is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps6ej.png) (note that the button is cut exactly where the button bar should be). I used as a model the fullscreen fragment provided in android studio, and these are the flags used in it.

```
 int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
```

I also tried adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`in the fragment's root layout but it didn't work.

**EDIT**
The problem is somehow caused by the FragmentContainerView that is not fullscreen. I tried setting the background to it instead of to its parent and the image has been cut: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMhBZ.png)

The main activity layout is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/colourful_sound_waves_pattern_phone_wallpaper__1_"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.LOCAL.FullscreenContainer"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="@style/Widget.Theme.LOCAL.ButtonBar.Fullscreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your activity layout xml?

Comment: I have posted the layout!

Comment: I have the same issue, I had <fragment> in the past and works fine, after move to <FragmentContainerView> stops working

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout), it is generally used to hold a single child, and as you are calculating height of linearlayout runtime, so its not gettting its aquired height.
Instead of the second Framelayout tag you should use Constraintlayout and add button as child of linearlayout. Something like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/colourful_sound_waves_pattern_phone_wallpaper__1_"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.LOCAL.FullscreenContainer"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="@style/Widget.Theme.LOCAL.ButtonBar.Fullscreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```